# Python Program to find calculate sub Patents related to a Patent

Tags: python-3.x

I have an input file as:

1 1.232
1 1.45
1 1.153
1 1.100
1 1.77
1 1.170
1 1.111
1 1.11
1 1.220
1 1.3
1 1.169
1 1.189
1 1.19
1 1.236
1 1.67
1 1.160
1 1.205
1 1.68
1 1.92
2 2.179
2 2.206
2 2.59
2 2.111
2 2.163
2 2.12
2 2.93
2 2.75
2 2.20
2 2.29
3 3.233

Need to show output as:
Patent     Number of Associated Sub-patents
1           4
2           3
3           5

Please help me how to write the same in Python

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read this: 'How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example' --https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve